# How to pass the values from a 3 vector tuple in a for loop to use in a class

Tags: c++, class, vector, tuples

I'm quite new with c++ and I have received a c++ project to 6 control a robot. My job is to change the control part and the trajectory generation part of the robot which I have done, but I'm struggling when importing another class tuple that consist in 3 vectors with the position, velocity and acceleration of the robot.

Basically the "PointTrajGenerator.cpp" creates a trayectory for each axis consisting in position, speed and acceleration in a tuple.

In the main.cpp I created the variable that stores the actual 4 vectors here:

```
std::tuple <std::vector<QVector6> , std::vector<QVector6> , std::vector<QVector6>> theTrj = PointTrajGenerator::getQuinticTraj(qsInit, qsFin, dqsInit, dqsFin, ddqsInit , ddqsFin , t0, tf, sampling_time);
```

Now, all I need to to is to send in every iteration of the loop the first 3 values of each vector into the "getCommand" function that I have created so I cand do all the computations inside the ImpCtrleSet.cpp. Here is whe I have the problem, I dont know how to pass this information.

```
qs = robot.getPosAxisI();
u = overalCtrl.getCommand(qs);

//it should look something like this? 
// out of the loop
position = std::get<0>(theTrj);
velocity = std::get<1>(theTrj);
accceleration = std::get<2>(theTrj);

//inside the loop
qs = robot.getPosAxisI();
u = overalCtrl.getCommand(qs,position[i],velocity[i],accceleration[i]);
```

Can anyone help me to figure out how to pass this information to the control part? I did some trials but no way I can make this work. This project is beyond my knowledge of programming in some parts so its pretty hard for me to understand all the code.

If more code is needed, just ask me... I'm exausted as I dont see how to do this.

PS: I'm 100% sure that many parts of the code ar super nasty and not efficient, as I said, I'm pretty new so I'm doing my best here.

**PointTrajGenerator.cpp**

```
#include "PointTrajGenerator.h"

//#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include "Eigen/Dense"
#include "TypeDefinitions.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

using namespace ourTypeDefinitions;

std::tuple <std::vector<QVector6> , std::vector<QVector6> , std::vector<QVector6>> PointTrajGenerator::getQuinticTraj(QVector6 qv6Ini, QVector6 qv6Fin,  QVector6 dqv6Ini,
                                          QVector6 dqv6Fin, QVector6 ddqv6Ini, QVector6 ddqv6Fin, double t_0,
                                          double t_f, double sampling_time)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> individualQ(6);
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> individualdQ(6);
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> individualddQ(6);

    std::vector<QVector6> qv6Traj;
    std::vector<QVector6> dqv6Traj;
    std::vector<QVector6> ddqv6Traj;

     for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            std::tuple <std::vector<double>, std::vector<double>, std::vector<double>> AllTraj =
                      getQuinticTraj(qv6Ini[i], qv6Fin[i], dqv6Ini[i], dqv6Fin[i], ddqv6Ini[i], ddqv6Fin[i], t_0, t_f, sampling_time, false);
            std::vector<double> individualQ = std::get<0>(AllTraj);
            std::vector<double> individualdQ = std::get<1>(AllTraj);
            std::vector<double> individualddQ = std::get<2>(AllTraj);
        }

     //posicion
          for(unsigned long int i=0;i<individualQ[0].size();i++)
          {
            QVector6 point={individualQ[0][i], individualQ[1][i], individualQ[2][i],
                            individualQ[3][i], individualQ[4][i], individualQ[5][i]};
            qv6Traj.push_back({point});
          }

          //velocidad
          for(unsigned long int i=0;i<individualdQ[0].size();i++)
          {
             QVector6 point={individualdQ[0][i], individualdQ[1][i], individualdQ[2][i],
                             individualdQ[3][i], individualdQ[4][i], individualdQ[5][i]};
             dqv6Traj.push_back({point});
          }

          //aceleracion
          for(unsigned long int i=0;i<individualddQ[0].size();i++)
          {
             QVector6 point={individualddQ[0][i], individualddQ[1][i], individualddQ[2][i],
                             individualddQ[3][i], individualddQ[4][i], individualddQ[5][i]};
             ddqv6Traj.push_back({point});
           }
           return std::make_tuple(qv6Traj, dqv6Traj, ddqv6Traj);
     }
std::tuple <std::vector<double>, std::vector<double>, std::vector<double>> PointTrajGenerator::getQuinticTraj(double q_0, double q_f,
                                                                            double dq_0, double dq_f, double ddq_0, double ddq_f, double t_0,
                                                                            double t_f, double samplingTime, double DEBUG)

{
    MatrixXd A(6, 6);
    VectorXd b(6);

    int n_time = ceil((t_f - t_0) / samplingTime);
    float time = n_time;


    A << 1, t_0, pow(t_0, 2), pow(t_0, 3), pow(t_0, 4), pow(t_0, 5),
        0, 1, 2 * t_0, 3 * pow(t_0, 2), 4 * pow(t_0, 3), 5 * pow(t_0, 4),
        0, 0, 2, 6 * t_0, 12 * pow(t_0, 2), 20 * pow(t_0, 3),
        1, t_f, pow(t_f, 2), pow(t_f, 3), pow(t_f, 4), pow(t_f, 5),
        0, 1, 2 * t_f, 3 * pow(t_f, 2), 4 * pow(t_f, 3), 5 * pow(t_f, 4),
        0, 0, 2, 6 * t_f, 12 * pow(t_f, 2), 20 * pow(t_f, 3),

        b << q_0, dq_0, ddq_0, q_f, dq_f, ddq_f;

    VectorXd a = A.colPivHouseholderQr().solve(b);


    RowVectorXd  q_traj(n_time);
    RowVectorXd  dq_traj(n_time);
    RowVectorXd  ddq_traj(n_time);

    int cont = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n_time; i++)
    {
        cont = cont + 1;
        time = t_0 + i * samplingTime;

        q_traj(i) = a(0) + a(1) * time + a(2) * pow(time, 2) + a(3) * pow(time, 3) + a(4) * pow(time, 4) + a(5) * pow(time, 5);
        dq_traj(i) = a(1) + 2 * a(2) * time + 3 * a(3) * pow(time, 2) + 4 * a(4) * pow(time, 3) + 5 * a(5) * pow(time, 4);
        ddq_traj(i) = 2 * a(2) + 6 * a(3) * time + 12 * a(4) * pow(time, 2) + 20 * a(5) * pow(time, 3);

    }

    std::vector<double> q_tr(q_traj.data(), q_traj.data() + q_traj.size());
    std::vector<double> dq_tr(dq_traj.data(), dq_traj.data() + dq_traj.size());
    std::vector<double> ddq_tr(ddq_traj.data(), ddq_traj.data() + ddq_traj.size());

    if (DEBUG)
    {
        std::cout << "Here is the matrix A:\n" << A << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Here is the vector b:\n" << b << std::endl;
        std::cout << "The solution is:\n" << a << std::endl;

        std::cout << "The traj is:\n" << q_traj << std::endl;
        std::cout << "The dtraj is:\n" << dq_traj << std::endl;
    }

    return std::make_tuple(q_tr, dq_tr, ddq_tr);
}
```

**impCtrlSet.cpp**

```
/*
 * impCtrlSet.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: 18 jul 2023
 *      Author: mikel
 */

#include "ImpCtrlSet.h"
#include "MathHelper.h"
#include "KukaProxy.h"
#include "DynamicComponents.h"
#include "Kine.h"
#include "KukaModel.h"
#include "JacobianFunctions.h"
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace Eigen;


ImpCtrlSet::ImpCtrlSet(double samplingTime): sampling_time(samplingTime)
{
  Km<< 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100;

  Dm<< 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1;

  Mm<< 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1;

}

QVector6 ImpCtrlSet::getCommand(QVector6 qs)
{

  QVector6 command= { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f , 0.0f , 0.0f, 0.0f };

  KukaModel kr6Model(KukaModel::ModelID::KR6_R700);
  DynamicComponents dynComp;
  JacobianFunctions Jacob;
  Eigen::VectorXd KmDiagonal = Km.diagonal();
  Eigen::VectorXd DmDiagonal = Dm.diagonal();
  QVector6 qd, dqd,ddqd;

// HERE I NEED TO BRING THOSE 3 values here  

//qd is position
//dqd velocity 
//ddqd accelreation

    qd=MathHelper::deg2rad(qd);
    dqd=MathHelper::deg2rad(dqd);
    ddqd=MathHelper::deg2rad(ddqd);

    std::cout << endl << "qd " << qd << endl << "  qs "<< qs <<  endl;

    std::cout << endl << "dqd " << dqd << endl << "  dqs "<< dqs <<  endl;

    std::cout << endl << "ddqd " << ddqd << endl << "  ddqs "<< ddqs <<  endl;

    //desired and actual robot position
    QVector6 preqd = qd;
    QVector6 preqs = qs;

    //calcular el forward kinematics de la trayectoria deseada y la posicion actual
    xs = kr6Model.fkAxisAngle(qs,6);
    std::cout << endl << "xs " << xs << endl;

    xd = kr6Model.fkAxisAngle(qd,6);
    std::cout << endl << "xd " << xd << endl;

    //calcular la velocidad de la trayectoria deseada y actual
    dqs=(qs-preqs)/sampling_time;
    std::cout << endl << "dqs " << dqs << endl;

    dxs= Jacob.getJacobian(qs) * dqs;
    //std::cout << endl << "dxs " << dxs << endl;

    dxd = Jacob.getJacobian(qd) * dqd;
    std::cout << endl << "dxd " << dxd << endl;

    //calcular la aceleracion de la trayectoria deseada y actual
    ddqs=(dqs-predqs)/sampling_time;
    ddxs= Jacob.getJacobian(qs) * ddqs + Jacob.getJacobianDerivate(qs,dqs) * dqs;                                                                                   //ddqd
    ddxd= Jacob.getJacobian(qd) * ddqd + Jacob.getJacobianDerivate(qd,dqd) * dqd;

    //compute dynamic parts of control
    inertMat = dynComp.getMassMatrix(qs);
    //std::cout << endl << "inertMat " << inertMat << endl;

    corCentrMat = dynComp.getCentrCor(qs,dqs);
    //std::cout << endl << "corCentrMat " << corCentrMat << endl;

    gMat = dynComp.getGravity(qs);
    //std::cout << endl << "gMat " << gMat << endl;

    Mm=inertMat;

    //compute errors
    xe=(xd-xs);
    dxe=(dxd-dxs);
    std::cout << endl << "xe " << xe << endl;
    std::cout << endl << "dxe " << dxe << endl;

    //calculate spring and damper
    spring=Km*xe;
    //std::cout << endl << "spring " << spring << endl;
    damper=Dm*dxe;
    //std::cout << endl << "damper " << damper << endl;

    //compute impedance component of the loop
    imp = (Jacob.getJacobian(qs)).inverse()*(ddxd-Jacob.getJacobianDerivate(qs,dqs)*dqs)+Mm.inverse()*(spring+damper);

    // compute torque
    tau = Mm*imp + corCentrMat + gMat;
    std::cout << endl << "tau " << tau << endl;

    //forward dynamics, get acceleration
    ddqForward = Mm.inverse() * (tau - corCentrMat - gMat);
    std::cout << endl << "ddqForward " << ddqForward << endl;
    command=ddqForward;

    preqd = qd;
    preqs = qs;
    predqs = dqs;
    predqd = dqd;

  return command;
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "PointTrajGenerator.h"
#include "TrajHelper.h"
#include "MathHelper.h"
#include "KukaProxy.h"
#include "ImpCtrlSet.h"
#include "DynamicComponents.h"
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <filesystem>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
  KukaProxy robot;
  robot.init();

  QVector6 qs = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f , 0.0f , 0.0f, 0.0f };
    // DEF TRAJ
  QVector6 qsInit = { 0.0f, -90.0f, 90.0f , 0.0f , 45.0f, 0.0f };
  //QVector6 qsFin = { 0.0f, -90.0f, 90.0f , 0.0f , 45.0f, 0.0f };
  QVector6 qsFin = { 0.0f, -40.0f, 60.0f , 0.0f , -90.0f, 0.0f };

  //qsInit = MathHelper::deg2rad(qsInit);
  //qsFin = MathHelper::deg2rad(qsFin);

  QVector6 dqsInit = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f , 0.0f , 0.0f, 0.0f };
  QVector6 dqsFin = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f , 0.0f , 0.0f, 0.0f };

  QVector6 ddqsInit = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f , 0.0f , 0.0f, 0.0f };
  QVector6 ddqsFin = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f , 0.0f , 0.0f, 0.0f };

  std::vector<double> dqPrev = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f , 0.0f , 0.0f, 0.0f };
  std::vector<double> qPrev = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f , 0.0f , 0.0f, 0.0f };
  std::vector<double> deltaq = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f , 0.0f , 0.0f, 0.0f };

  double t0 = 0.0f;
  double tf = 40.0f;
  double sampling_time = 4.0e-3;

  std::vector<std::vector<double>> dqForward(6, std::vector<double>(10000));
  std::vector<std::vector<double>>  qForward(6, std::vector<double>(10000));

  //std::vector<QVector6> theTrj = PointTrajGenerator::getCubicTraj(qsInit, qsFin, dqsInit, dqsFin, t0, tf, sampling_time);
  std::tuple <std::vector<QVector6> , std::vector<QVector6> , std::vector<QVector6>> theTrj = PointTrajGenerator::getQuinticTraj(qsInit, qsFin, dqsInit, dqsFin, ddqsInit , ddqsFin , t0, tf, sampling_time);


  ImpCtrlSet overalCtrl(sampling_time);

  if(!overalCtrl.setTrajectory(theTrj))
      std::cout<<"could not set the trajectory"<<std::endl;

  double initTime = 0.0;
  double totalTime = 0.0;
  int nAxis = 6;

  TrajHelper::confVectorToFile("puntos.csv", std::get<0>(theTrj), false);

  std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begint = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  QVector6  u = { 0,0,0,0,0,0 };       // Consigna
  std::vector<double> uVector = { 0,0,0,0,0,0 };

  for(unsigned int iter=1; iter<10000;iter++)
  {
    robot.refreshImmage();
    qs = robot.getPosAxisI();
    qs = MathHelper::deg2rad(qs);

    // OJO! devuelve la aceleracion deseada
    u = overalCtrl.getCommand(qs);

    uVector = MathHelper::q6v2stdV(u);
    //FORWARD DYNAMICS TO GET THE NEXT POSITION
    if (iter == 1)
        {
            std::cout << endl << "deltaq: " << endl;
            for (int j = 0; j < nAxis; j++)
            {
                dqForward[j][iter] = dqForward[j][0] + uVector[j] * sampling_time;
                qForward[j][iter] = qForward[j][0] + dqForward[j][iter] * sampling_time;
                //std::cout << "qForward: " << qForward[j][iter] << endl;
                deltaq[j]=qForward[j][iter]-qPrev[j];
                std::cout  << deltaq[j] << endl;
                dqPrev[j]=dqForward[j][iter];
                qPrev[j]=qForward[j][iter];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << endl << "deltaq: " << endl;
            for (int j = 0; j < nAxis; j++)
            {
                dqForward[j][iter] = dqForward[j][iter - 1] + uVector[j] * sampling_time;
                qForward[j][iter] = qForward[j][iter - 1] + dqForward[j][iter] * sampling_time;
                //std::cout << "qForward: " << qForward[j][iter] << endl;
                //std::cout << "q_fd iter - 1: " << q_fd[j][iter - 1] << endl;
                deltaq[j]=qForward[j][iter]-qPrev[j];
                std::cout << deltaq[j] << endl;
                dqPrev[j]=dqForward[j][iter];
                qPrev[j]=qForward[j][iter];
            }
        }

    robot.sendCommand(deltaq);

    std::cout << "u " << iter << std::endl;
    //std::cout << endl << "iter " << iter << endl;
//    std::cout << "qForward: " << qForward << endl;

  }
```

```
u = overalCtrl.getCommand(qs);

//it should look somthing like this? 
position = std::get<0>(theTrj);
velocity = std::get<1>(theTrj);
accceleration = std::get<2>(theTrj);

u = overalCtrl.getCommand(qs,position[i],velocity[i],accceleration[i]);
```

Comment: Do you really need tuple, a dedicated struct with named members might be better.

Comment: `std::vector<double> individualQ = std::get<0>(AllTraj);` is useless, you declare a local variable (hiding the one in upper scope) no longer used. You probabl want `individualQ[i] = std::get<0>(AllTraj);`.

Comment: I dont need a tuple exactly, I just find this way to save those three vectors bit it could be in any other way. What I want is to pass in each cicle the values of those 3 vectors into the getCommand function